# Use Angular 6 Directive to set property on a component

Tags: angular

I have a custom component ComponentA with an input property Format
I can use it like this:

```
<componentA Format="#.00"></componentA>
```

ComponentA is a 3rd party component I do not want to touch.

I would like to build a directive named MyFormatDirective that will set the property on that component to a fixed value of "#.00", so that instead of the above I can write:

```
<componentA MyFormat></componentA>
```

This is ofcourse a simplification. In reality I would like the directive to set multiple properties - basically custom configure the component

Creating a component that wraps it is not an option, since componentA is a part of a large structure of a 3rd party library that relies on specific DOM structure. Wrapping it breaks that. Moreover, I need this approach to set multiple types of configurations by multiple directives

Pls help me to acheive that, or suggest an alternative

Comment: Why not create a component that wraps `componentA` and provides the default values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 6 custom element directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980832/angular-6-custom-element-directives)

Comment: creating a directive that will only be used on one component kinda misses the point. i'd go with what user1849994 suggested. create a wrapper component

Comment: Creating a component that wraps it is not an option, since componentA is a part of a large structure of a 3rd party library that relies on specific DOM structure.  Wrapping it breaks that. Moreover, I need this approach to set multiple types of configurations by multiple directives

Comment: is @Eugene Mihaylin suggestion worked with you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a directive with the same selector (or a different one, but then you'll have to add an attribute to the component), and inject the component inside:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentAComponent } from './component-a.component';

@Directive({
  selector: 'component-a'
})
export class ComponentADirective {
  constructor(cmp: ComponentAComponent) {
    cmp.format = '#.00';
  }
}
```

Complete demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnxqqz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent-a.directive.ts

Comment: Hi. For some reason it does not work when the directive selector name is different then the component. (and this is what I actually need, since I want to have different directives for the same component)

Comment: Any chance you can help me to fix that?

Comment: Found the problem, had to put [ ] in the selector name to make it take a different selector. Thanks